# group by is not working with union in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am facing one issue with my query in which group by is not working with the union. 
Below is the query:

```
(select products.*, sum(100000) as count1, product_sku.price AS sku_price, product_sku.label AS sku_label from `products` left join `product_sku` on `products`.`id` = product_sku.product_id AND product_sku.is_primary = "Yes" AND products.is_variation = "Yes" where `product_name` = "testproduct1" and `status` = "Active" and exists (select * from `campaign` where `products`.`exclusive_for` = `campaign`.`id` and `status` = "Published" and `active_inactive` = "Active" or `products`.`exclusive_for` is null) group by `products`.`id` having id != 0)

union

(select products.*, ROUND ( (LENGTH(products.product_name)- LENGTH( REPLACE ( products.product_name, "testproduct1", "") ) ) / LENGTH("testproduct1") ) AS count1, product_sku.price AS sku_price, product_sku.label AS sku_label from `products` left join `product_sku` on `products`.`id` = product_sku.product_id AND product_sku.is_primary = "Yes" AND products.is_variation = "Yes" where (`products`.`product_name` LIKE "%testproduct1%" or `products`.`description` LIKE "%testproduct1%") and `status` = "Active" and exists (select * from `campaign` where `products`.`exclusive_for` = `campaign`.`id` and `status` = "Published" and `active_inactive` = "Active" or `products`.`exclusive_for` is null) having id != 0 )
group by `p_id`
```

please help me.

Comment: *not working* means?

Comment: it gives me syntax error.

Comment: Then add the error message to your question

Comment: Please add your error in question. So that we can easily track your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
(select products.*,
sum(100000) as count1, 
product_sku.price AS sku_price,
product_sku.label AS sku_label 
from `products`
left join `product_sku` on `products`.`id` = product_sku.product_id 
AND product_sku.is_primary = "Yes" AND products.is_variation = "Yes"
where `product_name` = "testproduct1" and `status` = "Active"
and exists (select * from `campaign` where `products`.`exclusive_for` = `campaign`.`id` and `status` = "Published" and `active_inactive` = "Active" or `products`.`exclusive_for` is null) group by `products`.`id` having id != 0)

union

(select * from 
(select products.*,
ROUND ( (LENGTH(products.product_name)- LENGTH( REPLACE ( products.product_name, "testproduct1", "") ) ) / LENGTH("testproduct1") ) AS count1,
product_sku.price AS sku_price,
product_sku.label AS sku_label
from `products`
left join `product_sku` on `products`.`id` = product_sku.product_id 
AND product_sku.is_primary = "Yes" AND products.is_variation = "Yes" 
where (`products`.`product_name` LIKE "%testproduct1%" or `products`.`description` LIKE "%testproduct1%") and `status` = "Active"
and exists (select * from `campaign` where `products`.`exclusive_for` = `campaign`.`id` and `status` = "Published" and `active_inactive` = "Active" or `products`.`exclusive_for` is null) having id != 0 )A
group by A.`p_id`)
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'A.p_id' in 'group statement'